# can't use withFrame in page class content

Tags: groovy, automated-tests, spock, geb

I am using geb-spock. I am trying to validate content of the page class, in the page itsself so that I just call the variable or functions. Using functions. I did something like this

```
class BasePage extends Page {
    static content = { 

       verifyheader { withFrame ("myFrame") { assert $("h1").text() == "Header1" } 

    }
  }
}



  ...

then: 
  to BasePage  
and: 
  verifyheader
```

> > I am getting an error that the test failed and withFrame is null.
> >     This does not occuer when I put the withFrame in the test case

```
  then: 
    to BasePage
  and: 
   withFrame('myFrame') {...}
```

This worked perfectly, but I am looking to use it in the page class. Is it possible? How can I go about it? or in other words, what is wrong with my code

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `withFrame` call in your content definition returns null because the last statement inside of the block passed to it is an assertion which always returns null. You should not assert inside of your content definition but in your test instead:

```
class BasePage extends Page {
    static content = { 
       headerText { withFrame("myFrame") { $("h1").text() } }
  }
}
```

and:

```
when:
    to BasePage

then:
    headerText == "Header1"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer